# Unable to install nuget packages from VSTS nuget using VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, azure-devops

Unable to install nuget packages from visual studio team services nuget server using VS2012

```
PM> install-package <package_name> -Source https://<vsts_hostname>/_packaging/Components/nuget/v3/index.json
```

**Error Message:-**

```
install-package : An error occurred while loading packages from 'https://<vsts_hostname>/_packaging/Components/nuget/v3/index.json': 
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1 install-package <package_name> -Source https://<vsts_hostname>...

+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

**PS:-**
The same install-package command works fine with VS2015 and VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using v2 endpoint instead. (replace v3/index.json to v2):

```
install-package <package_name> -Source https://<vsts_hostname>/_packaging/Components/nuget/v2
```

On the other hand, you can add the VSTS feed to nuget source: `nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT} -StorePasswordInClearText`, then right click the project in VS=> Manage NuGet Packages =>Online=>Select the package source you added.

Comment: Didn't help. Getting the same error while using v2 as well

Comment: @SureshRaja Add the VSTS feed to nuget source: nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT}, then right click the project in VS=> Manage NuGet Packages =>Online=>Select the package source you added.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT. I had to use -StorePasswordInClearText additionally to get it working.